# How to record an unknown geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, null-geometry

In the [QGIS Python API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.isEmpty)  it states that "a null geometry will always return true for isEmpty()."

For a geometry, a relational database *null* refers to an unknown geometry.  For example, if I had a database table of roads, for a particular road I might know the name and even the suburb, but, I don't know the line (representing the path the road takes).  This could happen because one person in my team enters the text attributes and then another digitises the road.  In this example, if I don't know the line for the road path I give a *null* (meaning unknown).

Now, say I have a database table that has one column for suburb boundaries (polygon), and, another column contains the lines of all the roads in each suburb (multi-line).  Now, when I have a suburb without any roads then I put an *empty* geometry in the line containing column.  This *empty* geometry lets me know that it is known that that there are no roads (lines) in a particular suburb (polygon).

The logic that we use in a database like PostGIS is that *empty* is known and one of many possible values for a *null* as it is unknown.  But, in QGIS the logic is that *null* is one of several possible values for *empty*.

Is there a test in QGIS for an ***unknown*** geometry that does not imply that the geometry is also *empty*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While isEmpty will return true for null geometries, isNull will return false for non null, but empty geometries. So you could combine the tests to check for non null empty geometries:

```
really_empty = g.isEmpty() and not g.isNull()
```